# Error when amplify pull --appId into an empty directory or project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have an amplify project. The backend is a aws lambda project in Python. I want to pull the backend environment into a new folder/empty project.
I do the following:

```
 amplify pull --appId xxxxxxxxxxx --envName env
```

It supposed to pull the project into an empty directory. However, I get the following error:

```
 ⠙ Confirm login in the browser or manually paste in your CLI login key:
  Successfully received Amplify Studio tokens.
   Amplify AppID found: xxxxxxxxxxx. Amplify App name is: app
   Backend environment dev found in Amplify Console app: app
    Failed to pull the backend.

   ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 
    '/Users/app/amplify/.temp/#current-cloud- 
    backend/function/lambda_app/src/env/bin/python'

    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 
     '/Users/app/amplify/.temp/#current-cloud- 
    backend/function/lambda_app/src/env/bin/python'
```

The directory, new_app, is an empty directory. Hence, it does not include any amplify folders etc..
Also, if I do

```
   amplify init
```

it creates a new appId and I cannot do "amplify pull" as it is a different appId.